# How to make the diff of files generated by 2 git fast-exports into a patchable file

Tags: linux, git, version-control, git-fast-import

I have 2 repos, repo1 and repo2 each with just one branch such that the repos can be graphed as such:

repo 1: `A --- B --- C`

repo 2: `A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- F`

From here I want to  run `git fast-export --all > export1` on repo1 and `git fast-export --all > export2` on repo2 so that I have two text files "export1" and "export2".

I then run `git diff export1 export2 > diffs.patch` to get the diffs from the `git fast-export` and in theory containing just information on commits, `D --- E --- F`.

How do I modify diffs.patch and what commands do I use so that I can apply the patch on an isolated repo3, which looks like this:

repo3: `A --- B --- C --- G`

so that it will look like this once the patch file is modified, emailed, and applied:

repo3-patched: `A --- B --- C --- G --- D --- E --- F`.

This MUST be done without using `git bundle` (can't use binary files) and `git format-patch` (I want to patch tags and branches as well, which to my knowledge, `git format-patch` cannot do).

Comment: Was it your question where @torek explained how to convert binary files to text and back? What was wrong with the solution?

Comment: Yes, it was. The problem was that when I decoded the `git bundle`, the text file wasn't descriptive of what the bundle contained - which is a requirement that I should have mentioned.